# JSF templating and controller invocation

Tags: jsf, templates, dynamic, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I'm new to JSF, I've read some of the specs but there are still many things I don't understand.

I have joined a project with JSF1.2 + Richfaces 3.3 + some EL that allows to call methods with parameters.

I have created a template xhtml that is meant to be reusable, and I have a bean that holds all the data the template needs to build and render itself. The bean is referenced in the controller.

The template take 2 parameters, the **controller** and a string value **feature** that is used to produce the bean that holds the data. I do something very ugly to invoke the method that will produce the bean on the controller :

```
<h:outputText value="#{controller.loadFeature(feature)}" />
```

Then I use the bean that is referenced by the controller to build the view

```
<ui:include src="#{controller.myLoadedBean.widgetPath}">
```

I need this bean at the build time because depending on the data, I have to include other nested xhtml templates. But I don't know how to manage this :

- If the controller is request-scoped, the loadFeature method is invoked too late, at the RENDER_RESPONSE phase, the view is not built with the loaded data
- If the controller is session-scoped, it's even worse, the loadFeature method in invoked at the RENDER_RESPONSE, so the first time I try to load the page I have an error, and the the pages are build with the data of the previous request.

*Basically, what I need is to be able to call a method of the controller with a template parameter at the view build time.*

I don't know how to achieve this, or if it is possible at all. Maybe there are some other mechanism in JSF I don't know of that allow a controller to be invoked before/when the view is being built.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: Hi! I want my widget to be extandable and allow other developers to add their own nested widgets. They would then put the path to their xhtml in a config file, read by the controller and provided to the include tag. Is there a better way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got my template working. I was wrong, JSF and Facelet components should not call a method so they can fill themselves.

The correct MVC way is to call a method of the controller before, the controller will build the view bean and then only redirect to the JSF view.